# WP_User_Query returns empty array

Tags: wordpress

I'm running WordPress 4.6.1. I'm including an array of user IDs to get the final result. This query works fine with fewer array items, but returns an empty array if the array has more than ~3000 user IDs.

Here's my code:

```
$args['include'] = array(0 => 152, 1 => 5426, 2 => 3057, 3 => 5763, 4 => 1720, 5 => 3103, 6 => 5148, 7 => 198, 8 => 5582, 9 => 5309, 10 => 1489, 11 => 3404, 12 => 3812, 13 => 3385, 14 => 2211, 15 => 3487...);
$args['orderby'] = 'include';

$results = (new WP_User_Query( $args ))->results;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to include array without keys, i mean:

```
$args['include'] = array(152,5426,3057,5763,1720,3103...);
```

Comment: I have tried including just the values in the array. It returns the records when I have less than ~3000 items in the array. When I have more items, it returns an empty array.

Comment: Hmm, really strange. 

For your FIY - Array size is limited only by amount of memory your server has. If your array gets too big, you will get "out of memory" error. In your case you are getting empty results array.

Here are two ways i would suggest you:
1. try to increase your memory in php.ini
or
2. try to split $args['include']  array into two or more (depends how much records you'll have)